# Multiple accounts on iPhone Developer Program

Tags: iphone, account

I am a developer at iPhone Developer Program assigned to the project for the company. I would like to buy my own licence to develop as an independent programmer. How to do it? Do I need another Apple ID?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

No, you can be a member of multiple development teams with a single Apple ID.  The developer website will ask you which team you'd like to work on when you sign in.

Comment: I'm trying the same thing, but I don't see how to accomplish this.  When I edit my ADC Personal Profile, it only provides one "organization" field, and all the people shown in the "people" tab are my coworkers.  How do you set up a second team/organization for personal projects?

Comment: You need to sign up for a completely new Apple Developer account as a new organization, either you as an individual or under a new business name, and then add your AppleID as a person on that account.

Comment: If you will upload an app from your originial account - how will it be displayed on the App Store?  as the company or as your own account?

Comment: This should not be marked as the answer of the question due to incomplete information i.e. the op asked HOW to add an additional organization, and that information has not been provided here.

Comment: How to remove any member from team in my development account ?

Answer (score 9):

I highly recommend not using the same Apple ID for multiple developer programs.

You can do it, but anytime it prompts you to log in, it also prompts you to "Select Your Team". As a separate step. Both on the web and in XCode.

It slows me down and I haven't found any way to make it always choose one as the default rather than asking every time.

[**Update**: My original answer is well over a year old, and I had been living with the annoyances for a while before posting. I *just* had our administrator send me a new invitation to my corporate email address so I wouldn't have the conflict. It took me almost no time at all to get my profiles set up again and it's **so** much nicer to not have to "choose your program" all the time.

So if you set things up this way and you've just been living with it, don't. Save yourself the annoyance and time and just get re-added to the program with a different email address.]

Comment: Have you found a way to leave a team? I'm on 3 and I want off one of them, how the heck can you LEAVE a team?

Comment: The team admin should be able to remove you. I haven't figured out how to delete my individual account from being associated with my Apple ID, leaving only the team.

Comment: it slows you down? As opposed to what, logging in with a different id each time? This doesn't make any sense to me

Comment: @wkhatch In my case I always select my company's account as my team--I'm not actively using my personal developer account. However, I still have to choose my team any time I do anything with provisioning profiles, etc. If I had just left them in separate Apple IDs, I wouldn't ever get prompted.

Comment: @Peter Jenkins, yes, I understand all that, but you'd still need to login (Xcode or portal) each time you did anything that required authentication, and what I meant was in response to your statement that it slowed you down. I don't see the difference between choosing from a select as an extra step, vs. having to change the login credentials prior to that step (and thereby skipping it) each time. I guess it's just a personal preference; I think keeping the same creeds in the window and just selecting is quicker. To each his own ;-)

Comment: @wkhatch I don't think I really understand you. It still prompts me to log in. But then it also prompts me to choose a team. If I didn't have two teams with the same account, I'd only have to log in, and not have to choose a team.

Comment: @wkhatch - In my case, with multiple accounts, every time I try to do any action within the Developer site it asks me to select which team to use, and if I wait more than ~5 seconds to reply, it then generates an error. The Apple Developer site is buggy as hell when you have multiple accounts, it is to be avoided...

Comment: @Justin, I've never experienced what you describe. To each his own, I guess ;-)