# iPhone Developer Program; Adding a personal subscription to a team account?

Tags: iphone, ios, registration

I have an "Apple ID" (which I assume is Apple's way of saying "account") that is associated with two iPhone Developer Programs as a team member.  I'm trying to add a personal Developer Program subscription using this same Apple ID.  I found this answer here, which implies that it should/may be possible (some of the comments seem to contradict the accepted answer):

[Multiple accounts on iPhone Developer Program](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1819464/multiple-accounts-on-iphone-developer-program)

So I went and paid my $99 using my current Apple ID.  I got an "Order Acknowledgement" e-mail from Apple shortly after placing the order.  If I follow the order status link in the e-mail, my order shows up as being "Electronically Delivered".  However, when I log into the Apple developer portal, I am not given the option to choose my personal subscription.  I can only choose between the two companies at which I am a team member.

So my questions are:

1. Is the question cited above correct in that I should be able to do what I am trying to do?
2. Does Apple send any communication after the "Order Acknowledgement" message, or is that all I should expect to get?
3. How am I supposed to log into my personal subscription?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give it a little time. I don't think the 'order acknowledgement' means that the account has been created or is ready to use. It can take 24 hours before the account is created, perhaps longer over a weekend. So, wait at least 24 hours from when you submitted the application before you get too worried. BTW, the "electronically delivered" bit just means that they're not going to ship anything to you with this purchase.

You can check the status of your application in the [iOS developer portal](http://developer.apple.com/devcenter/ios/index.action). Look for the "Check the status of your pending iOS Developer Program enrollment" link in the right hand column.

If the issue doesn't resolve itself after a day or two, contact Apple's developer support group: you can reach them by phone at 800-633-2132.

To address your question specifically:

1. Yes, you can definitely use the same AppleID to be a member of several development teams. However, a single AppleID can only be in the "team agent" role for a single account. If you're the agent for your company, you'll need to create a different AppleID for your personal account. (You'll know if it you're the agent -- you'll have to accept changes to Apple's developer agreement on behalf of your company every time they change it, which is at least several times each year.)
2. Yes, I believe you'll receive additional communication when your account is ready, or if there's any problem in creating your account.
3. Once your personal account is set up, you'll have to choose which development team you're using each time you log into the developer portal.

Comment: Thanks, though I'm not seeing a "Check the status of your pending iOS Developer Program enrollment" link anywhere.  All I have on the right are three "Read about accessing ..." links.

Comment: @aroth: Strange. Just to be clear, it's the last item (just after "News and Announcements") in a box titled "iOS Developer Program". Make sure that you're not already logged into the portal and you should see it.

Comment: Ah, I see, I thought I had to be logged in to see it.  If I log out I see it, but clicking it just asks me to log in, which then prompts me to choose which team account I want to use (between the two existing companies).  Once I do that it just takes me to the standard iOS dashboard page, it does not appear to actually provide any details about the enrollment status of my personal subscription.  I guess I'll have to wait it out a bit longer, and maybe contact support if it's not resolved in a day or so.