# IOS: one account two iOS developer program

Tags: ios, iphone-developer-program

If I'm enrolled in one iOS developer program with a specific Apple ID, can I add that exact same account to another iOS developer program.

In the case where I'm working for two sellers in the app store, is it possible and/or desirable assuming I don't mess up and confuse things on any one occasion?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1819464/multiple-accounts-on-iphone-developer-program

Comment: @Brad Larson -  Sir, the 1st paragraph of the FAQ: "... if your question generally covers ... " [followed by  3rd bullet] "* software tools commonly used by programmers ".  XCode is required for iOS. Production code requires testing on real devices. Apple requires certificates to use real devices. XCode integrates those certificates. Only a licensed developer can install same VIA the software development ***tool chain*** (Xcode). AND, if your ***accounts*** get conflated, there be dragons (See Apple Tech.Note 2250). Beryllium's answer helped me. It's a valid question, just not asked well.

Comment: @HowardPautz - This is not a question about Xcode, but one about Apple's policies regarding their developer program. After some debate, it was decided that questions about iTunes Connect which were more about the business side of things rather than tools (provisioning, submission, etc.) were off-topic for the site. See here for an example of some of the reasons why this is: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/106008/where-should-i-ask-questions-about-submitting-my-app-to-the-app-store . However, I'll give this the benefit of the doubt and reopen it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Possible. If you enroll in multiple teams(programs) then after login you  have to select your team. In each team you work in accordance with your role and permissions.

[image]