# IOS: one company two IOS developer program

Tags: ios, iphone-developer-program

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [IOS: one account two iOS developer program](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9379791/ios-one-account-two-ios-developer-program)

excuse me if it's not a programming question, but I have this problem

the problem is that now I'm enrlolling in a iOS developer program (I'm using fictitious names), with a company called "My Company", ok?

then when I release an app in app store I see on the top "App Store > Games > MYCOMPANYONE " (it's an example)

and below on the left there is

Category:...

Version:..

Size...

and

"Developer: My Company"

it's all ok and now I explain my problem.

Now I want enrlonn in an other iOS developer program but ever with the same "My Company" but in app store when I release an app it must be so:

on the top "App Store > Games > MYCOMPANYTWO"

and below on the left

Category:...

Version:..

Size...

and

"Developer: My Company"

with the same company

is it possible this?

can you help me please?

Comment: Hmm, which store are you looking at? The U.S. store says "Seller: My Company", not "Developer: ..."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, this is not possible.

When you purchase one developer license, you get one license. The developer name that the user sees is whatever you entered when you set up the iTunes Connect account, and cannot be changed. This is, in part, to prevent abuse.

If you want to release a second product with a different developer name, you'll have to register a new company to do so and pay the $99 again.

Comment: yes I want to register another account with another name, but I want to use the same "legal information company"; at example my company name is DeveloperFunny and it stay in England; so with this DeveloperFunny I want to enroll it in two developer ios program and pay 99$ two times; is it possible?

Comment: Apple developer program registration requires a registered legal entity name; you can't use a DBA or fictitious name. If you want a second account with a different name, you'll need a second registered legal entity. You could also create a personal account, but then that would show up with your own name as the developer.

Comment: in the two case I use a legal entity, but this enity is the same entity "DeveloperFunny", but in app store I want show that is product by developer program A, and not is product by developer program B, and the opposite...I have only a company, but I want two different developer ios programs

Comment: No, this isn't possible either. You have to use the legal entity name. Even in the first case, you couldn't have company "DeveloperFunny" and team "Funny A" and have the team name show up in the store; you have to give Apple the company name, and they use that. If you want `FunnyA` and `FunnyB`, then you need legal entities with those names.

Comment: though this thread is old, i just want to add, that i got the response from apple that the actual name that is displayed in the store under your app's name can be different than the name of your company. they said it can't be changed later, only on signup though. so i guess there are two fields, a name and a company (legal) name.